# Distributions of differences and sums of normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

**1)** Bean bags are automatically completed by a machine, with an average weight per bag of $60$ kg, standard deviation of $1.5$ kg and normal distribution. In the storage and transport process, the average loss per bag is $1.2$ kg and standard deviation of $0.4$ kg, also with normal distribution.

a) Calculate the probability that in a consignment of $140$ bags of beans, the total weight will not exceed $8230$ kg.

b) Calculate the probability that in a shipment of $140$ bags of beans, the total weight is between $8000$ and $8400$ kg

Can anyone give me some tips on the above issues? I don't know anything like that

Comment: Is $84000$ kg right? $8400$ kg, perhaps?

Comment: @Patricio yeah yeah

Comment: Do you know how to find probabilities on the form $P(X\leq a)$ in terms of integration?

Comment: This is a long multi-part problem. Begin by finding population mean and standard deviation for consignments. Then use normal tables to get the required probabilities. My answer provides an outline with some intermediate results to help you organize your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I begin with some basic facts. You should look for
the corresponding formulas in your text or class notes. (I predict this is not the last use you will have for these formulas.)

The adjusted weight $A$ of a single bag after shipping
has $E(A) = 60 - 1.2 = 58.8,$ $Var(A) = 1.5^2 + .4^2 = 2.41,$ and $SD(A) = \sqrt{2.41} = 1.5524.$

Also, the weight $C$ of a consignment of 140 bags
has $E(C) = 140(58.8) = 8232$ and $SD(C) = \sqrt{140}(1.5524) = 18.3682.$

And the weight $C$ of the
consignment has $C \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 8232,
\sigma = 18.3682).$

---

You seek $P(C \le 8230) = 0.4566$ and
$P(8000 < C < 8400) \approx 1.$ These probabilities can be found directly in R as shown below, or by standardizing
and using printed normal CDF tables (possibly a little less precisely, where rounding is necessary).

```
pnorm(8230, 8232, 18.3682)
[1] 0.4566473
diff(pnorm(c(8000,8400), 8232, 18.3682)) 
[1] 1
```

I'm pretty sure you're expected to
get the probabilities using normal tables. I will leave that to you. (What are z-scores corresponding to consignment values 8230, 8000, and 8400?)

---

Mainly for visualization, here is a simulation of a million consignments with summary statistics and a histogram. (Well... also it's a way to check my
arithmetic.)

Mean, standard deviation, and proportions from a million consignments match population mean, population SD, and probabilities (to about two decimal places).

```
set.seed(2021)
c = replicate(10^6, sum(rnorm(140,60,1.5)-rnorm(140,1.2,.4)))
summary(c);  sd(c)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   8147    8220    8232    8232    8244    8321 
[1] 18.36845  # SD of simulated values

mean(c <= 8230)
[1] 0.456224   # aprx P(C < 8230)
mean(c >=8000 & c <= 8400)
[1] 1          # aprx P(8000 < C < 8400)
```

[image]

```
hdr = "Simuulated Consignment Weights with Normal Density"
hist(c, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x, 8232, 18.37), add=T, lwd=2)
 abline(v = 8230, col="orange", lwd=3, lty="dotted")
```